# What to look for when buying a second hand packraft?

Tags: gear, boats, packrafting

I'm going to buy a one-man packraft, capable going some wilder stuff. For the beginning I would like to try it with a **used one**.

What should I look for when buying a **second hand** packraft?

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/19262/8794

Comment: I have voted to close as duplicate, as the OP points out the criteria for a new or used are presumably the same.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I don't think its a dupe, since if you are buying used, there are things like making sure it holds air and checking to see if it has been patched a bunch of times or has lots of scrapes that you wouldn't have to check if you were buying new

Comment: Having brought faulty new products in my time @CharlieBrumbaugh might be worth doing those on both anyway.